# Ruby on Rails Use Model Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have the `rails_best_practices` gem and I'm getting the following warning:

`APP/app/controllers/users_controller.rb - use model association (for @user_answer)`

in reference to this gist of code:

```
begin
  @user_answer = @user.user_answers.where(:question_id => @question_id).first
  if @user_answer
    @user_answer.answer_id = @answer_id
    @user_answer.save!
    @message = 'Answer updated successfully!'
  else
    @user.user_answers.create(:question_id => params[:questionId], :answer_id => params[:answerId])
    @message = 'Answer submitted successfully!'
  end
rescue ex
  @message = ex.message.split(':')[1].chomp
end
```

but according to the [page on model association](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2-use-model-association) it doesn't look like it's violating this, it looks like it is following along correctly. Am I missing something about this?

Comment: Which line is line 33?  I think it is complaining about "@user_answer.answer_id = @answer_id" which looks like similar to smell that is explained in the link you shared

Comment: whoops I removed the line number that was to point to the method where this code lies (so the line number doesn't actually help in solving this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in directly accessing the variables in the `@user_answer` object, and not updating the `user_answer` within the `@user` variable...and since Rails has an [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) method, we can do this like so:

```
begin
  @user_answer = @user.user_answers.where(:question_id => @question_id).first
  if @user_answer
    @user.user_answers.update(:question_id => @question_id, :answer_id => @answer_id)
    @message = 'Answer updated successfully!'
  else
    @user.user_answers.create(:question_id => @question_id, :answer_id => @answer_id)
    @message = 'Answer submitted successfully!'
  end
rescue ex
  @message = ex.message.split(':')[1].chomp
end
```

But we can do better. Rather than differ by create and update, we can simply use Ruby's short circuit evaluation to create a `@user_answer symbol and update it whether it is new or not.

```
begin
  @user_answer = @user.user_answers.where(:question_id => @question_id).first || @user.user_answers.new
  @user_answer.update_attributes!(question_id: @question_id, answer_id: @answer_id)
  @message = 'Answer submitted successfully!'
rescue ex
  @message = ex.message.split(':')[1].chomp
end
```